# switch case calls undefined variable

Tags: php, html, switch-statement

I have a problem with the variable

```
(define ('THIS_PAGE', basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) );
```

which I call in my sites title tags like

```
<title> <?=$title?><?=SITE?></title>.
```

The Site constant displays just fine but the $title variable returns an error of '<br `/&gt; &lt;b&gt;Notice&lt;/b&gt;:  Undefined variable: title in lt;b&gt;/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/scc/sccc_2014/_240php/05a_dynamicContentc/_inc/inc_header.php&lt;/b&gt;`

on line

```
&lt;b&gt;6&lt;/b&gt;&lt;br /&gt; MAX-O-MATIC
```

which is displayed in my title tag. I am working locally using MAMP, but I don't think this is the issue. I'm hoping that it is just a typo, but I'm still very new and it could be anything.

Any help is appreciated.
Yes I've tried to research a solution before, and spent time trying to debug. I wouldn't come here to ask for help without doing proper diligence. 
Thank you

CONFIG FILE:

```
define ('SITE', 'MAX-O-MATIC'); //Name of Site

define ('THIS_PAGE', basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) ); //Constant Current Page is X

switch(THIS_PAGE)
{
    //Set most likely scenario as the first to run
    case 'index.php' :
       $title = "Welcome" ;
       $banner = "Max-o-matic";
       break;

    case 'itc240.php' :
       $title = "ITC240 |" ;
       $banner = "Samples";
       break;

    case 'itc250.php' :
       $title = "ITC250 |" ;
       $banner = "Samples";
       break;

    default :
       $title = "";
       $banner = "Default Banner";
}
```

HEADER FILE:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>

    <title>
            <?=$title?><?=SITE?>
    </title>
```

TEST PAGE:

```
<?php
//itc240.php
include '_inc/inc_config.php';   //My arrays and stuff
include '_inc/inc_header.php';
?>

test Content</p>

<?php
include '_inc/inc_footer.php';
?>
```

Comment: You don't appear to have included the config file before executing the header file...

Comment: I suspect a scope issue. SITE is defined, think global. $title is defined in a script and lacks the same global nature. For example if you define $site outside of a function and try to access it in a function without declaring ```global $site``` (in the function) or passing it in as a variable you will not be able to use it as intended. More info needed.

Answer (score 1):

How are you loading that config file?

Make sure it is loaded before you try outputting your $title.

Comment: I love the config file with an include, and it loads before the header which is also an include like so: "<?php include '_inc/inc_config.php'; include '_inc/inc_header.php'; ?> <p>test content</p> <?php include '_inc/inc_footer.php';?>

Comment: do a var_dump($title) after your switch(...){ } do it output anything?

Comment: I attempted this doing an echo statement (<?php echo var_dump($title); ?>) and got back a similar error (Notice: Undefined variable: title in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/scc/sccc_2014/_240php/05a_dynamicContent-fail/itc240.php on line 8 NULL)

Comment: great. Seems like your basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) evaluates to NULL. If NULL is passed to switch, it has this weird thing that it evaluates case 0: - that you don't have. To confirm this - try doing <? echo basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) ?> just before switch.

Comment: I did as you asked, which had me doing that in the config file. It returned the following error ('Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'switch' (T_SWITCH), expecting ',' or ';' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/scc/sccc_2014/_240php/05a_dynamicContent-fail/_inc/inc_config.php on line 27')

Comment: I realized i forgot the ';' after the echo statement. So i updated it and got this error message (Notice: Undefined variable: title in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/scc/sccc_2014/_240php/05a_dynamicContent-fail/itc240.php on line 7
NULL)

Comment: so since you didn't see an output of echo basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) - that means that basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) returns NULL on your local MAMP. That is the problem. For fun, add this line "case 0: echo 'AHA! HERE IS THE PROBLEM!';break;" to your switch, remove double quotes ;)